Fetching and processing transaction information
I have this rust code to fetch information about a transaction.
In the debugger I can see that the information is recieved, but I can not access it. I keep geting this error:

Error { request: Some(GetTransaction), kind: SerdeJson(Error("invalid type: null, expected struct EncodedConfirmedTransactionWithStatusMeta", line: 0, column: 0)) }

 async fn get_transaction(sign: &Signature) {
        let web_client = RpcClient::new(HTTPS_URL.to_string());
        match web_client
            .get_transaction(sign, UiTransactionEncoding::JsonParsed)
            .await
        {
            Ok(result) => {
                println!("{:?}", result);
            }
            Err(err) => {
                println!("Error: {:?}", err);
            }
        }
    }

